# Alternative to static JdbcTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, jdbctemplate

I have implemented Abstract DAO Factory in Spring.

I have two autowired methods as follows:

```
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {

    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}


@Autowired

 public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

At the beginning the jdbcTemplate and dataSource get right values in them. But when i call constructor of the class using the new keyword , in which the above methods are written, jdbcTemplate and dataSource get set to NULL.

But if i declare them as static then the previous right values are retained.

I wonder if there is any alternative to static in spring if i want to retain the previous values of the above two ?

Comment: You shouldn't use new to get a Spring component. That's the mistake. You should use dependency injection, which is what Spring is all about.

Comment: If you make the jdbcTemplate and dataSource fields @Autowired, then spring manages the lifecycle of these objects. You should not create instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should you @Component on top of your class to get the objects values of dataSource and jdbcTemplate. you should not use new keyword of a class to get the autowired references.

Below code may help to your question.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ledara.demo")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dmds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dmds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dmds.setUrl("yourdburl");
        dmds.setUsername("yourdbusername");
        dmds.setPassword("yourpassword");
        return dmds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

and below class has autowired fields of jdbcTemplate and dataSource

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class SampleInfo{

    @Autowired(required=true)
    DataSource getDataSource;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate;

    public void callInfo() {
        System.out.println(getDataSource);
        System.out.println(getJdbcTemplate);

    }

}
```

And below is the main class

```
public class MainInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
        context.refresh();
        SampleInfo si=context.getBean(SampleInfo.class);
        si.callInfo();
    }

}
```